# Xcode update doesn't support iphone 5s

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, version

I updated my Xcode to 11.2. I developed one application. When I try to run my app on iPhone 5s I can't. It says my iPhone's iOS version is lower than the target version. Xcode 11.2 doesn't support 5s or lower?Please anyone give me the clear explanation about this.

Comment: I think you need to change your project target version.

Comment: pls check your iPhone 5s os version, and set your app target os to your iPhone os or older.

Comment: iphone's os version is 12.4.3.When i change project target to 12.4,I ended up with errors in SceneDelegate and AppDelegate file.Is there any other way?

Comment: Its better to set your project target to be less than your iPhone os version.

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI requires iOS 13.0+. Don't use SwiftUI for unsupported devices. Xcode 11.2 still allows using UIKit for older iOS devices.